# Opening deep link from parent tab does not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

When using a `react-navigation` deep link to open a details view it only successfully navigates when you are not on the parent tab. I have this issue in a big project of ours but I have been able to replicate it with an example project. In the example project the deep link works when pressing the button on the `SettingsScreen` but not on the `HomeScreen`

The code is the following:

App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {Button, View, Text, Linking} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Open deeplink"
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL('testapp://details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Open deeplink"
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL('testapp://details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen, path: ''},
    Details: {screen: DetailsScreen, path: 'details'},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
);

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: AppNavigator, path: ''},
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

const prefix = 'testapp://';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer uriPrefix={prefix} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "awesomeproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**v6 update:**

App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {Button, Linking, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Details!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Deep link"
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('testapp2://details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Deep link"
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('testapp2://details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: {
      screens: {
        Details: 'details',
      },
    },
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['testapp2://'],
  config,
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "awesomeprojectv5",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there's some bugs in handling deep link in nested navigators, please try upgrading to v5

Comment: I tested with v6 and experience the same behaviour

Comment: I tested with v5 and it works fine, let me test with v6 when free

Comment: I tested with v6 and it works fine

Comment: What react native version are you on?

Comment: Also, if you could share the test project that would be great :)

Comment: are you testing on iOS or Android?

Comment: Also, did you complete all the setup in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)?

Comment: Tested on both platforms. Yes I completed all the setup in the docs

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on your v6 update:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {Button, Linking, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Details!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Deep link"
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('testapp2://details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Deep link"
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('testapp2://details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      // <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} /> <-- remove this screen
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const config = {
  screens: {
    HomeStack: { <-- rename to HomeStack
      screens: {
        Details: 'details',
      },
    },
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['testapp2://'],
  config,
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStackScreen} /> <-- rename to HomeStack
        <Tab.Screen name="SettingsStack" component={SettingsStackScreen} /> <-- rename to SettingsStack
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```